# Rails Model: Protected methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, protected

```
    class demo
        protected 
        def method1
        end

        def methods2
        end
    end
```

Will above syntax treat both of methods as protected or only first one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both methods will be protected